# Display polyhedra from dmccooey vertex and face information

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

Dmccooey is a site that contains 3D virtual models and coordinates of a large variety of polyhedra.

An example of a coordinates file you can retrieve from the site is:

```
Propello Tetrahedron (canonical)

C0 = 0.139680581996106531822799916239
C1 = 0.509755332493385520099017792717
C2 = 0.606267870861478462919986663126

C0 = (cbrt(4 * (11 + 3 * sqrt(69))) - cbrt(4 * (3 * sqrt(69) - 11)) - 1) / 3
C1 = (cbrt(4 * (25 + 3 * sqrt(69))) + cbrt(4 * (25 - 3 * sqrt(69))) - 5) / 3
C2 = (cbrt(4 * (371 + 33*sqrt(69))) + cbrt(4 * (371 - 33*sqrt(69))) - 1) / 33

V0  = (  C1,   C0,  1.0)
V1  = (  C1,  -C0, -1.0)
V2  = ( -C1,  -C0,  1.0)
V3  = ( -C1,   C0, -1.0)
V4  = ( 1.0,   C1,   C0)
V5  = ( 1.0,  -C1,  -C0)
V6  = (-1.0,  -C1,   C0)
V7  = (-1.0,   C1,  -C0)
V8  = (  C0,  1.0,   C1)
V9  = (  C0, -1.0,  -C1)
V10 = ( -C0, -1.0,   C1)
V11 = ( -C0,  1.0,  -C1)
V12 = (  C2,  -C2,   C2)
V13 = (  C2,   C2,  -C2)
V14 = ( -C2,   C2,   C2)
V15 = ( -C2,  -C2,  -C2)

Faces:
{ 12,  0,  2, 10 }
{ 12, 10,  9,  5 }
{ 12,  5,  4,  0 }
{ 13,  1,  3, 11 }
{ 13, 11,  8,  4 }
{ 13,  4,  5,  1 }
{ 14,  2,  0,  8 }
{ 14,  8, 11,  7 }
{ 14,  7,  6,  2 }
{ 15,  3,  1,  9 }
{ 15,  9, 10,  6 }
{ 15,  6,  7,  3 }
{  0,  4,  8 }
{  1,  5,  9 }
{  2,  6, 10 }
{  3,  7, 11 }
```

Each time that I want to open such a polyhedron in mathematica, I copy the information and manually adjust it to fit the language for mathematica.

For example, I rewrote the information above to the code shown below:

```
C0 = 0.139680581996106531822799916239;
C1 = 0.509755332493385520099017792717;
C2 = 0.606267870861478462919986663126;

V0  = {  C1,   C0,  1.0};
V1  = {  C1,  -C0, -1.0};
V2  = { -C1,  -C0,  1.0};
V3  = { -C1,   C0, -1.0};
V4  = { 1.0,   C1,   C0};
V5  = { 1.0,  -C1,  -C0};
V6  = {-1.0,  -C1,   C0};
V7  = {-1.0,   C1,  -C0};
V8  = {  C0,  1.0,   C1};
V9  = {  C0, -1.0,  -C1};
V10 = { -C0, -1.0,   C1};
V11 = { -C0,  1.0,  -C1};
V12 = {  C2,  -C2,   C2};
V13 = {  C2,   C2,  -C2};
V14 = { -C2,   C2,   C2};
V15 = { -C2,  -C2,  -C2};

vTSIc = {};
For[i = 0, i <= 79, i++;
    AppendTo[vTSIc, ToExpression[StringJoin[{"V", ToString[i-1]}]]]
    ]
    
fTSIc = {{13,  1,  3, 11}, {13, 11,  10,  6}, {13,  6,  5,  1}, {14,  2,  4, 12}, 
    {14, 12,  9,  5}, {14,  5,  6,  2}, {15,  3,  1,  9 }, {15,  9, 12,  8}, 
    {15,  8,  7,  3}, {16,  4,  2,  10}, {16,  10, 11,  7}, {16,  7,  8,  4}, 
    {1,  5,  9}, {2,  6,  10}, {3,  7, 11}, {4,  8, 12}};

Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Thick}], Polygon /@ Map[vTSIc[[#1]] & , fTSIc, {2}]}], PlotRange-> All,Boxed -> False]
```

[image: canonical propello tetrahedron]

I am sure there must be a more efficient way than manually changing all curved brackets () seen for the vertices V0-V15 to the curly ones {}, adding semi-colons ; to the end of the lines and copy-pasting the faces in a new list.

I am wondering if anyone has done this before or if there are ways to automate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the polyhedra already built-in in Mathematica? Have a look at `PolyhedronData[]`

Comment: Oh no I wasn't aware. Thank you! I didn't know there were so many built in in Mathematica. I cannot find the propellor solids in the list, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getDMMCCOOEYpolyhedron = 
  Import["http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/" <> # <> ".txt", "Lines"] &;

split =  If[Length[#] == 4, Drop[#, {2}], #] & @
  Map[DeleteCases["Faces:" | ""]] @
  Split[Drop[#, 2], ! StringStartsQ["Faces" | "V0" | "C0"] @ #2 &] &;

processStrings = Map @ 
  StringReplace[{"cbrt" -> "CubeRoot", "sqrt" -> "Sqrt", 
    "(" ~~ a__ ~~ ")" /; StringContainsQ[a, ","] :> "{" <> a <> "}",
    "=" ~~ a : Shortest[__] ~~ "=" ~~ __ :> "=" <> a}];

coordsAndFaceIndices = If[Length @ # == 2, {0, 1} + #,
  {#2, 1 + #3} & @@ #] & @ ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm] &;


fromDMCCCOOEY = coordsAndFaceIndices @* processStrings @* 
  split @* getDMMCCOOEYpolyhedron;
```

***Examples:***

```
{coords, faceIndices} = fromDMCCCOOEY @ "PropelloTetrahedron";

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon @ faceIndices], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[#, Polygon@#2], Boxed -> False] & @@ 
 fromDMCCCOOEY["GreatDisdyakisDodecahedron"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[#, Polygon@#2], Boxed -> False] & @@ 
 fromDMCCCOOEY["IcositruncatedDodecadodecahedron"]
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this approach with "Cube" I get an error saying " Function::slotn: Slot number 3 in {#2,1+#3}& cannot be filled from ({#2,1+#3}&)[{{0.5,0.5,0.5},{0.5,0.5,-0.5},{0.5,-0.5,0.5},{0.5,-0.5,-0.5},{-0.5,0.5,0.5},{-0.5,0.5,-0.5},{-0.5,-0.5,0.5},{-0.5,-0.5,-0.5}},{{0,1,5,4},{0,4,6,2},{0,2,3,1},{7,3,2,6},{7,6,4,5},{7,5,1,3}}]." And it doesn't print

Comment: @PTeeuwen, please use the updated `coordsAndFaceIndices` .

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to use built-in function `PolyhedronData[]` as proposed by @Sjoerd C. de Vries and want to train your Mathematica programming, you can automate the whole process of parsing the file. Below is an example – not the optimal or the most pedagogical one – of how you can do it by combining several functions for string and expression manipulation.

```
parseDmccooeyFile[fileName_] := 
  Module[{replaceParentheses, parse, initString, facesString, rules, vertices, faces},
   replaceParentheses[s_String] := 
    If[StringCount[s, ","] == 2, StringReplace[s, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}], s];
   parse[s_String] := 
    ToExpression[s, TraditionalForm, Hold] /. sqrt -> Sqrt /. 
        cbrt -> CubeRoot /. Set -> Rule // Rationalize // ReleaseHold;
   
   {initString, facesString} = StringSplit[fileString, "Faces:"];

   rules = parse@*replaceParentheses /@ 
     Drop[StringSplit[initString, ("\r" | "\n") ..], 1];
   
   vertices = Last /@ Select[rules, 
       StringTake[SymbolName[First[#]], 1] == "V" &] /. Reverse[rules];

   faces = Part[vertices, # + 1] & /@ (ToExpression /@ 
       StringSplit[facesString, ("\r" | "\n") ..]);
   
   {vertices, faces}
   ];

{vertices, faces} = parseDmccooeyFile["data.txt"]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I am a bit stuck though still as I don't know yet how to import data.txt to the mathematica workspace and to then use it? I know about << Import["/Users/...../data.txt"] >>, but I don't know yet how to use it as input to the function you have written.

Comment: You just use `parseDmccooeyFile["/Users/.../data.txt"]`.

Comment: Oh that does make sense. Thanks!